# EF4 Mapping varbinary(max) to Binary - Code First Error

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a POCO class called `Attachment` that maps to a table in SqlServer with a VarBinary(max) field in it. The field contains files.

The POCO class looks like this

```
public class Attachment
{
    public string AttachmentId { get; set; }
    public string AttachmentTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Binary Data { get; set; }
}
```

The Mapping looks like this

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Attachment>().Property(a => a.Data).HasColumnName("col_data");
```

However the mapping is throwing an error

```
The type 'System.Date.Linq.Binary' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as a parameter 'T'
```

The mapping works fine if I use a byte array but this seems to be corrupting the data on the way through.

The file in the database has an initial binary string like:-

```
0x504B0304140008000800027923400000000000000000000000001F000000
```

I think this is a JPG file. 
Any help getting the file out of the DB in one piece would be appreciated.

Comment: Google suggests that `0x504B0304` is an indicator of a zipfile: http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=0x504B0304, if that helps any? (I would have thought a `byte[]` array is the right way to proceed, by the way.)

Comment: What makes you think it's corrupted?

Comment: Thanks Owen, That's exactly what it was. Makes sense now I know what it is. I'm now able to unzip the file and stream the contents to the browser or file system.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`Binary` data type is only for Linq-to-Sql. EF is not able to work with it. The correct data type for EF is byte array (`byte[]`).